# Filter rows with remaining only the latest record in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, database, sqlalchemy

I have been trying to write the SQLAlchemy code that should function as the following SQL query.

```
SELECT * FROM events AS ev
INNER JOIN event_types AS et1 on ev.event_type_id = et1.id
INNER JOIN (
            SELECT event_type, MAX(created_at) AS LatestCreatedAt
            FROM event_types et GROUP BY event_type
    ) AS et2
ON 
et2.event_type = et1.event_type
AND
et2.LatestCreatedAt = et1.created_at
```

What I'm trying to do is to

1. Get all columns from the events table
2. Inner join the event_type table (et1) on the event table
3. Group by the event_type with only the rows that have the latest record (i.e. Filter out old event types by looking at created_at if duplicated)
4. Inner join the grouped event_type (et2) on the event_type table (et1)

What I wrote for the SQL Alchemy version of the above is

```
from sqlalchemy import func

subquery = session.query(EventTypeTable.event_type,
func.max(EventTypeTable.created_at).group_by(EventTypeTable.event_type)).all()

events = (session.query(EventTable)
          .join(EventTypeTable)
          .join(subquery)
          .all())
```

However, I get the following error.

```
 Neither 'max' object nor 'Comparator' object has an attribute 'group_by'
```

It seems to complain that I can not use group_by with max function. Is there any other way to get the query results while leaving only the latest record on the created_at column in the event_type table in SQL Alchemy?

Any help or comments are appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Try `subquery = session.query(EventTypeTable.event_type,
func.max(EventTypeTable.created_at)).group_by(EventTypeTable.event_type)`

Comment: Thank you! The subquery part worked! but now I'm getting a different error from the main query. I might be calling the subquery in the wrong way...

`'Query' object has no attribute 'is_selectable'`